# SQL to Excel - Max each sheet

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a SQL Table with close to 2 Million rows and I am trying to export this data into an Excel file so the stakeholders can manipulate data, see charts, so on...

The issue is, when I hit refresh, it fails after getting all the data saying the number of rows exceed max rows limitation in Excel. This table is going to keep growing every day.

What I am looking for here is a way to refresh data, then add rows to Sheet 1 until max rows limitation is reached. Once maxed out, I want the rows to start getting inserted into Sheet 2. Once maxed out, move to 3rd sheet, all from the single SQL table, from a single refresh.

This does not have to happen in Excel (Data -> Refresh option), I can have this as a part of the SSIS package that I am already using to populate rows in the SQL table.

I am also open to any alternate ways to export SQL table into a different format that can be used by said stakeholders to create charts, analyze data, and whatever else pleases them.

Comment: Excel has a *hard* limit of 1M individual rows. PowerPivot can handle far more data, but Excel itself can't exceed 1M rows. And you can't generate a PowerPivot model with SSIS

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Isn't the 1M limit per each Excel sheet, not file?

Comment: Rather than porting 2MM rows of raw data, perhaps your users can work with some reasonable aggregations.   Also take a look into Excel's add-in Power Pivot.

Comment: How is this going to fix the problem? What you try to do is already extremely inefficient. Never mind what happend to the UK with big Excel sheets. A client machine is *never* going to be as fast as a database server eg with columnstore indexes or tabular Analysis Services models

Comment: PowerPivot is the same engine used by Analysis Services. Except AS runs on the server, having far more RAM and CPU cores available than any client

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Looking at Power Pivot right now.. Thank you

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Inefficient, yes. But that is the requirement. They want an Excel file, nothing else. I already have a Power BI report and they are not happy with that already. I am going to try using Power Pivot.

Comment: `a different format that can be used by said stakeholders to create charts, analyze data, and whatever else pleases them.` that would be Power BI. You can export the data to Power BI *on Azure* and have them do whatever they want. 2M rows is almost no data for Power BI. You can also use Power BI Desktop to create reports, dashboards etc, and so can the end users.

Comment: @CrazyCucumber so did the UK government. Do the users *still* want that?

Comment: Yup, not sure why people are obsessed with Excel while there are better ways to provide them with the data and reports they want. The Power BI report provided has 15 bookmarks, 10 charts, several slicers, and possibly everything they can imagine. But guess what.... "WE WANT EXCEL!"

Comment: Again, are you *sure*? Almost all of the time this is caused by ignorance, failure to understand the costs involved, or fear of appearing ignorant. Sometimes it's brand loyalty (we want IBM!) but that doesn't apply here. If you explain the tradeoffs and costs, especially in light of the UK fiasco, they may change their opinion

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I am positive. We had a very lengthy meeting about why they want Excel. I tried my hardest to convince them otherwise. They were not pleased. They like the Power BI report, but they want to do other things with the data. Promising to include these reports they wanted in the Power BI report didn't convince them either. So, I don't have a choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sounding too facetious, you are suggesting a very inefficient method.

The best way of approaching this method is not to use .xlsx files at all for the data storage.

Assuming your destination stakeholders don't have read access to the SQL server, export the data to .csv and then use Power Query in some sort of 'Dashbaord.xlsx' type file to load the .csv to the data model which can handle hundreds of millions of rows instead of just 1.05m.

This will allow for the use of Power Pivot and DAX for analysis and the data will also be visible in the data model table view if users do want raw rows (or they can refer to the csv file..).

If they do have SQL read access then you can query the server directly so you don't need to store any rows whatsoever as it will read directly.

Failing all that and you decide to do it your way, I would suggest the following.

Read your table into a Pandas df and iterate over each row and cell of the dataframe, writing to an your xlsx[sheet1] using openpyxl then once the row number reaches 1,048,560 simply iterate to xlsx[sheet2].

In short: openpyxl allows you to create workbooks, worksheets, and write to cells directly.

But depending on how many columns you have it could take incredibly long.

Answer (score 1):

[Product Limitations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

> Excel 2007+  1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns

A challenge with your suggestion of filling a worksheet with the max number of rows and then splitting is "How are they going to work with that data?" and "Did you split data that should have been together to make an informed choice?"

If Excel is the tool the users want to use and they must have access to all the data, then you're going to need to put the data into a [Power Pivot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-pivot-overview-and-learning-f9001958-7901-4caa-ad80-028a6d2432ed) data model (and yes, that's going to impact the availability of some data visualizations). A Power Pivot model is an in-memory tabular data set. What the means is that the data engine, xVelocity, is going to use a bunch of memory but can get over the 1 million row limitation. Depending on how much memory is required, you might need to switch from the default 32 bit Office install and go with a 64 bit install (and I've seen clients have to max RAM out on old, low end desktops because they went cheap for business users).

Power Pivot will have a connection to your SQL Server (or other provider). When it refreshes data, it's going to fire off queries and determine the unique values in columns and then create a dictionary of unique values. This allows it to compress the data with low cardinality really well - sales dates are likely going to be repeated heavily within your set so the compression is good. Assuming your customers are typically not-repeat customers, a customer surrogate key would have high cardinality and thus not compress well since there's little to no repeat. The refresh is going to be dependent on your use case and environment. Maybe the user has to manually kick it off, maybe you have SharePoint with Excel services installed and then you can have it refresh the data on various intervals.

If they're good analysts, you might try turning them on to Power BI. Same-ish engine behind the scenes but built from the ground up to be an response reporting tool. If they're just wading through tables of data, they're not ready for PBI. If they are making visuals out of the data, PBI is likely a better fit.